# Unexpected behavior of JavaScript's Set object

Tags: javascript, set

Just spotted strange behavior of JS's Set object and decided to ask stackoverflow community :) 
So that's the problem: 
Screen from console:
[image]

Code for copy-paste:

```
let a = new Set([1])
let b = new Set([2, 3])
a.add(...b)  // result is set of {1, 2}
```

Problem is that set `a` does not contain value `3` after add function call.
This behavior have an explanation or it's more like a bug? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The add method on sets only accepts one parameter.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add

Comment: @Gerrit0 yep, that make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add create a new set like this:

```
let a = new Set([1])
let b = new Set([2, 3])
const c = new Set([...a, ...b])
```

Variable c contains all the items that you need.

The problem is that the add method of the set get only one parameter, no a arguments, if for that reason that only add one value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
let a = new Set([1])
a.add(2,3);
```

a will still only have 1,2 as elements. The spread operator is basically doing the same as above